# $_POST Method doesn't work $_GET does

Tags: php

I simply cannot get the $_POST method to work.
Instead $_GET contains the data

I used Postman to test via POST and GET method:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSCNc.png)

[Server PHP Settings](http://www.rising-games.net/phpinfo.php)

Request: ***.rising-games.net/posttest.php?test=Something

```
<?php
echo "Request method: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "<br><br>";

//-------------------------------------------
//  POST output
//-------------------------------------------
if (isset ($_POST ["test"]))
    echo "Post 'Test' is: " . $_POST ['test'] . "<br>";
else
    echo "Post 'test' is empty!<br>";

//-------------------------------------------
//  Get output
//-------------------------------------------
if (isset ($_GET ["test"]))
    echo "Get 'Test' is: " . $_GET ['test'] . "<br>";
else
    echo "Get 'test' is empty!<br>";

//-------------------------------------------
//  Request output
//-------------------------------------------
if (isset ($_REQUEST ["test"]))
    echo "Request 'Test' is: " . $_REQUEST ['test'];
else
    echo "Request 'test' is empty!";
```

?>

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to use post request. But you set value of `test` parameter not to message body of request but to get parameter `http://www.rising-games.net/posttest.php?test=Something`

Try this in Postman:
[image]

Comment: I did, and it worked. Thanks ^^ But my get is not empty like yours.

Comment: because I send request to http://www.***.net/posttest.php without get parameter. please mark this question as accepted if it works:)